# Objective-C: setValue: value forKey: xposition

Tags: ios, objective-c, setvalue

I am trying to create an "animation" effect for some objects in an NSMutableArray. I have it set up so every 2 seconds, the objects change their x value (I do not want to do an actual animation so please do not suggest one!):

```
- (void)jumpLeft {
    [self performSelector:@selector(jumpRight) withObject:nil afterDelay: 2.0];

    for (int i = 0; i < [self.jumpArray count]; i++) {
        [self.jumpArray[i] setValue:@(30*i) forKey: "XPOSITION"];
    }
}

- (void)jumpRight {
    [self performSelector:@selector(jumpLeft) withObject:nil afterDelay: 2.0];

    for (int i = 0; i < [self.jumpArray count]; i++) {
        [self.jumpArray[i] setValue:@(20*i) forKey: "XPOSITION"];
    }
}
```

Assume it continues throughout the game. My question is, what do I enter to make the x position change? I tried looking at what people have said, and I have not found anything. I also tried doing self.jumpArray[i].center = ... but it says "Property not found on object of type 'id'. Any suggestions?

Anything helps! Thank you in advance!

Comment: p.s. I am aware the values entered will not make it "jump left" or "jump right" they are more or less placeholders for the example.

Comment: What are the objects in `jumpArray`?  Are they `UIView`s of some sort?

Comment: they are UILabels -- sorry for not clarifying

Comment: You can't use property access on objects of type `id`. Instead, call the setter method. `[self.jumpArray[i] setCenter:someValue];`.

Comment: thank you rmaddy that worked perfectly! Would you like to write it as an answer so I can mark it correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `self.jumpArray` is an array of `UIView` objects, you can set the center using the setter method instead of using the property syntax:

```
[self.jumpArray[i] setCenter:somePointValue];
```

Another option is to make your code more readable:

```
UIView *view = self.jumpArray[i];
view.center = somePointValue;
```

You can also use fast enumeration:

```
for (UIView *view in self.jumpArray) {
    view.center = somePointValue;
}
```